# How to check whether current user exists or not?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I using the following code to check if the user exists then retrieve the data from the database, else do nothing, but when the application is loaded and user do not exist(I am user about this) it performs the database query which gives the error of

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

at this line

> self.checksetup = document.get("setupComplete") as! Bool

which should not happen as the user doesn't exists, I am using this in Swift IOS and using Firestore database and firebase authentication

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let user1: User = Auth.auth().currentUser!
        if let user: User = Auth.auth().currentUser! {
            let setupcheckref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
            setupcheckref.getDocument{(document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists{
                    let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"

                    self.checksetup = document.get("setupComplete") as! Bool

                    if self.checksetup == true {
                        if Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
                                           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeScreen", sender: self)
                                           SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                       }
                                       else{
                                           print("please verify your email")
                                           try! Auth.auth().signOut()

                                           let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message:
                                               "Please verify your email to Login! Check Your Inbox!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                           alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

                                           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                          // self.view.makeToast("please verify your email")
                                           self.sendEmailVerification()
                                           SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                       }

                    }

                    else{

                        self.view.makeToast("Please Setup Your Account!", duration: 2.5)


                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tocompletesetup", sender: self)
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    } }

            }

           // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeScreen", sender: self)
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let user: User = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        view.makeToast("Please Setup Your Account!", duration: 2.5)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tocompletesetup", sender: self)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        return
    }
    let setupcheckref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid)
    setupcheckref.getDocument { document, _ in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            if self.checksetup = document.get("setupComplete") as? Bool, self.checksetup {
                if user.isEmailVerified {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeScreen", sender: self)
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                } else {
                    print("please verify your email")
                    do {
                        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message:
                            "Please verify your email to Login! Check Your Inbox!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        // self.view.makeToast("please verify your email")
                        self.sendEmailVerification()
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    } catch {}
                }
            } else {
                print("check failed",self.checksetup)
            }
        } else {
            print("Document doesnt exists")
        }
    }
}
```